# How to insert a button to gmail page in firefox extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, inboxsdk

i want to develop an extension for both chrome and firefox and need to insert a button to gmail page. In chrome i use [Inboxsdk](https://www.inboxsdk.com/)  and it work very fine like this: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uy9n2.png)

Unfortunately, it looks like inboxsdk is not supported on the firefox extension. I tried to load the inboxsdk script but nothing happened on gmail. I want to ask **is there a way to use Inboxsdk on firefox extension? Or is there any other way to insert the button into gmail as inboxsdk?** Thankyou.

Comment: You can try dynamically creating the buttons and appending them to the Send button in the content.js.

Answer (score 0):

The InboxSDK is currently just supporting Chrome and Safari Browser extensions.

> What browsers are supported? Chrome and Safari are currently
>   supported. Chrome version 36 and Safari 7 are the minimum versions we
>   support.
>
> Firefox support is under consideration; please let us know if you're
>   interested.

[FAQ - Supported Browsers](https://www.inboxsdk.com/docs/#FAQ)

One approach to add buttons without InboxSDK to compose views could be using MutationObservers and check whenever a compose view is added to the DOM. Find the send button and append your own button dynamicly. The hard part will be to find a way how you can reliably identify compose views/send buttons.
Classnames could work but I'm  bot sure if gmail has consistent classnames and ids you can use (obfuscation etc.).